# Is there a way to remove the top bar in JSFiddle embedded view

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

When I go to the JSFiddle embedded full screen view (`<url of fiddle>/embedded/result`), there is always a bar at the top with JSFiddle on it, as shown here with where it says *result*:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this bar from the view?

***Note:***

You can also access this view by going to URL `<url of fiddle>/show`.

Comment: This question needs more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before you read, please note that jsfiddle is a nice site and they do this so that people can't just use them for hosting and then embed their links.**

**Consider that before removing all their branding - don't be a jerk.**

I don't know if they've changed this since Noel's answer, but it still shows the bar at the top for me.

It can still be done though.

Example:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/vmt32w4d/11/show/

The trick is to find the source of the iframe which is on `fiddle.jshell.net` as Noel suggests.

They keep this on a separate origin to give you a cross-origin exception if you try to access elements outside of the iframe.

This is no problem, just link to that instead and add the following code:

```
$("header",window.parent.document).remove();
$("#tabs",window.parent.document).css({
    'margin-top':'0px',
    'height':'100vh'
});
$("#result",window.parent.document).css({
    'margin-top':'0px',
    'height':'100vh'
});
```

I included the jquery library for this to work - otherwise you could just edit the code to alter the css using vanilla JS.

There may be a better way to alter the css or whatever, but now you know how to do so

Answer (score 2):

The embedded fiddle is just an iframe within another iframe. You can take the source from the child iframe and replace the parent one with it.

Starting from the */embedded/result url like in the image.

1. Inspect the parent iFrame with Dev Tools.
2. Copy the child iFrame source link (looks like '/fiddle.jshell.net/*blah*/*blah*/show/light/').
3. Replace the parent embed source link with the copied one.

That should do it. Worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me, the top bar keeps being added on the /show/light/ link